# How soon to follow up?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

I have been to second interviews recently and I have been given a clear timeline of when they will be making their decision which is2 weeks from the time of my second interview. 
I would like to follow up and let them know of my interest on top of the thank you note that I have already sent but wanted to understand if it would be appropriate to follow up before the deadline of 2 weeks?

In regards to the two linked questions ("[How do I properly follow up?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)" and "[If so how soon?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9939/is-it-a-good-idea-to-follow-up-after-an-interview-and-if-so-how-soon)") I do not believe that mine is a duplicate. My question is on when to follow-up, specifically the company has given me their timeline, which neither of these questions address.

Comment: This one is slightly different. It contains a specific question on when I should be following in the instance of me being issued a timeline

Comment: Again, this question did not have next steps issued to the candidate. I did. That is the difference.

Comment: I disagree, but I've edited your argument into the question so others can decide as well. It takes 5 votes or a moderator to close a question.

Comment: When you say follow up, is that a thank you follow up or a have you made a decision follow up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fine line between looking eager for the position and being a pest. ONe will help you and one will move you down the list.

When given a timeline like this, it is great to send one thank you after the interview but before the timeline date. It would not be too annoying to get  **one** other contact before the timeline date although it is unlikely to help your chances in the slightest. It would be moving into pest territory to do more than that.

Hiring officials are busy peopel trying to fit in the time to interview and discuss candidates to make a decision while holding down full time jobs doing something else. If you have sufficiently impressed them in the interview, they won't forget you. If you have not, contacting them further is not likely to change minds.

My personal opinion is that you have done what you can do in the interview and the follow-up thank you. Now it is time to show you have some patience and wait out their deadline.